# Problem running powershell command in Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: powershell, gitlab, gitlab-ci, enterprise-architect

I am trying to run a **GitLab CI/CD pipeline** with a job listing like below:

```
test-win:
  stage: test
  tags: ["windows_test"]
  script:
    - 'cd .\Modules\de.test\eaYamlExportTestAutomation\bin\Debug'
    - 'powershell.exe .\EAYamlExporter.exe "Test-Architecture-CM --- ;Connect=Cloud=protocol:http,address:test.de,port:80,user:username,pwd:password;Data Source=Test-Architecture;DSN=Test-Architecture" C:\Users\de.test\testModel\behaviors\stateMachine GuidListBehaviors.txt'  
    - 'cd .\Libraries\de.test.project\'
    - 'mvn test'
```

Powershell command accesses models from Enterprise architect cloud and generates some log. The format of the command is:

> EALogGenPlugin . exe <eap - file > < command for indicating
> exporter plugin needs to be invoked > < output folder > < text
> file containing list of UUIDs >

I am getting following error

[image: Gitlab CI error]

Is there any idea what can be the problem in the **powershell script**?

Comment: Obviously a missing parameter. Since you reddened that part it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Ok, creating the command on a separate powershell file and then running like below solved the issue:                                                                                                          `powershell -File ValidationsYAMLGenerationAutomation.ps1`

Comment: But right now I am getting another error like below:                                                               `unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {3A9E4F92-8D27-495B-8B22-1D702B3F0C83} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).`                                     which is coming straight from inside the  **.\EAYamlExporter.exe**. Any idea about this error and reason?

Comment: Googling for that code mentions 32/634 bit issues. EA is 32 bit. Your add-in obviously not.

Comment: That means should I build the c# class library project with x86 architecture? It's running fine in my machine, but not from gitlab ci/cd .

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. But there are several threads on Sparx' forum talking about 32/64 bit issues. You should at least try to go that path. There's a 64bit version of EA in the V16 beta.